# How to load xml on html page using google feed ? here the xml belongs to another server...brief example is below ... I need detail example

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="ROBOTS" content="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW" /> 
<script src="/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/jquery/jquery.jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/jquery/jquery.jgfeed.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<script type="application/x-javascript">
$.jGFeed('url', 
  function(feeds){
    // Check for errors
    if(!feeds){
      // there was an error
      return false;
    }
    // do whatever you want with feeds here
    for(var i=0; i<feeds.entries.length; i++){
      var entry = feeds.entries[i];
     alert(entry);

    }
  }, 10);
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you use Firebug or any other developer tools? Replace `alert(entry);` with `console.dir(entry);` and look up the structure of the data.

You may find the title, content and everything you need to construct the HTML (DOM to be exact) your want.